# Postman Variables

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to parse "Id" from below json to store it in a variable

```
{
    "cf35864e-944d-11e9-8aff-22000ab8d684": {
        "Id": "1a45b704-944e-11e9-8aff-22000ab8d684",
        "Name": "Test plan",
        "Type": "Limited",
        "Credits": 10119.70,
        "AvailableCredits": 500.100
    }
}
```

I've tried

```
bodydata =JSON.parse(responseBody)
planid=bodydata.cf35864e-944d-11e9-8aff-22000ab8d684.Id
console.log(planid)
```

But postman throws errors, is there any way so that only ID can be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `planid=bodydata["cf35864e-944d-11e9-8aff-22000ab8d684"]['Id']`

Answer (score -1):

As per your mentioned JSON data, the below may work.

> let resp = pm.response.json();
>
> console.log(resp.cf35864e-944d-11e9-8aff-22000ab8d684.Id);

Above will work only if "cf35864e-944d-11e9-8aff-22000ab8d684" value is static and only one object is returned.